# create virtual midi device on android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, midi

i need to create a virtual midi device for android. I was reading this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary but I didn't understand it, and I haven't seen examples of how to do it either. Can anybody help me? I have checked other technologies like Flutter or Juce but as far as I understood it is not possible and I have to use either Kotlin or Java. My goal is to create the virtual midi device and have it recognized by other apps within the android device, so I can have inter-app midi communication. Many thanks